# Python 3.4 strptime() not working

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert a string to datetime and it isn't working...

```
self.loadsList[loadID][5] = datetime.strptime(
self.loadsList[loadID][5]+" "+self.loadsList[loadID][6], "%x %X %z")
```

and it raises a Value Error.

```
ValueError: time data '11/08/2014 04:00:00 -0500' does not match format '%x %X %z'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!
(Python 3.4)

Answer (score 3):

The default `%x` format is the equivalent of `%d/%m/%y`, where `%y` matches a *two digit year*:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
'%m/%d/%y'
```

Your input uses a 4 digit year instead:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('11/08/2014', '%x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 14
```

I'd not use `%x` or `%X`, just spell out the date and time formats; based on your input and the use of `%x` that'd be:

```
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Demo:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('11/08/2014 04:00:00 -0500', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %z')
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 8, 4, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
```

It is not clear if your input represents the 8th day of November or the 11th day of August; your use of `%x` suggests the former but I suspect you should instead interpret the value the other way around:

```
'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

The alternative would be to switch your Python locale from the default `C` to `en_US` where the year *would* use 4 digits.